# Laravel with Mailgun timed messages

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

I have found a way to delay sending e-mail through Mailgun API. I am wondering if external HTML can be used somehow to include in the mail?

Now I am doing it like this:

```
$mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'XY<webmaster@xy.com>',
    'to'      => 'XY<xy@xy.com>',
    'subject' => trans('content.subject_confirm_event_registration'),
    'html'    => '<myHtmlCode />',
    'o:deliverytime' => Carbon::now()->hours(2)->toRfc2822String()
));
```

But the problem is when I try anything complex, which has like 100 lines of code, it doesn't look well, and I would like a solution where I can put external file in it so that it looks like this:

```
$mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'XY<webmaster@xy.com>',
    'to'      => 'XY<xy@xy.com>',
    'subject' => trans('content.subject_confirm_event_registration'),
    'html'    => file.blade.php
    'o:deliverytime' => Carbon::now()->hours(2)->toRfc2822String()
));
```

Comment: Maybe laravel Mailer can help you?
Also you can delay sending email in Queue.

Comment: Maybe, but there is a reason behind me using Mailgun :)

Comment: But laravel has Mailgun Swift Transport driver

Answer (score 0):

You can manually render a view by using `view()->render()`.

`Illuminate\View\View::render()` returns the string contents of the view. It is also used inside the class' `__toString()` method which allows you to echo a View object.

```
$mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'XY<webmaster@xy.com>',
    'to'      => 'XY<xy@xy.com>',
    'subject' => trans('content.subject_confirm_event_registration'),
    'html'    => view('some.template', $data)->render()
    'o:deliverytime' => Carbon::now()->hours(2)->toRfc2822String()
));
```